# html, js - how to limit elements "scope" - namespaces

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, namespaces

During last perioud I've seen more and more often the following situation.

Developer A creates a feature. Let's say is an autocomplete input. Let's assume **for simplicity** that no framework is used, html and js are on the same file. The file would look like this (let's also asume jquery used - is less to type):

```
<!-- autocomplete something.html file -->
.........................................
<input id="autocomplete" type="text" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#autocomplete').change(function() {
        // Do lots of things here -> ajax request, parsing, etc.
    });
</script>
.........................................
```

Now developer B sees the feature and says "Oh, nice feature, I can use that in my section, I'll put one at the top, and one at the bottom - because page is long".

And he does an **ajax call to get that html file** (this is important, I'm talking about features loaded like this, not features rewritten for the other section) and includes it where he needs it.

Now... problem. The first autocomple works, the second doesn't (because is select by id).

A workaround would be to modify, and use a class. And everything is ok, unless someone else (or himself, or whatever) uses same class for a tottaly different thing.

This could all be avoided if you could the the script to use as a "scope" (I know it is not the correct phrasing, couldn't find any better) the file where it was declared on.

Note: This is a theoretical question. For each particular case a solution could be found, but defining some kind of namespaces for this scenarios would solve the whole class of problems.

How could that be achieved?

Comment: Best I can come up with would be web components, but not sure if they support this scenario - I would assume so given they are aiming to be self-contained components of stuff.

Comment: See: HTML Imports (they come with their own document, similar to an iFrame so should probably solve the issue you're facing), specifically Example 2 under [imports](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/#link-type-import)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're accessing the DOM the only way I see would be to use the "old" inline event:

```
<!-- autocomplete something.html file -->
.........................................
<input onchange="autocomplete_change();" type="text" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function autocomplete_change() {
        // Do lots of things here -> ajax request, parsing, etc.
    };
</script>
...........
```

Now the function name cannot be used by Developer B.
But when accessing DOM some kind of restriction will always be there.

However when creating the input by Script you can bind the handler directly to the Element:

```
<script>
    var input = $('<input type="text"/>');

    input.change(function() {
        // Do lots of things here -> ajax request, parsing, etc.
    });
    document.body.appendChild(input[0]);
</script>
```

Comment: Ty for the answer and welcome to SO... not downvoting since it does address the point asked, but including the file twice would result in redefining same functions, redeclaring any global variables you would use, etc. May create more problems than solving.